# Choose firestore subcollection when connecting component to redux with react-redux-firebase

Tags: redux, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am using `react-redux-firebase`'s `fireStoreConnect()` middleware with 
a screen in my react-native mobile app. At the time of connecting the component to the redux store, I want to specify the firestore sub-collection I connect to, which depends on the user that is navigating the app.

How should I specify the collection in `firestoreConnect`? The user id is in the redux store.

MWE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

class PhotosScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> i plan the use this.props.images here </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    // reference the subcollection of the user
    const images = state.firestore.data.images;

    return {
        images: images,
    }
}

export default compose(
    firestoreConnect([
        {
            collection: 'users',
            doc: "HOW DO I GET THE USERS ID HERE? IT IS IN REDUX STORE",
            subcollections: [{ collection: 'images' }]
        }
    ]),
    connect(mapStateToProps),
)(PhotosScreen)
```

Comment: what version of `react-redux-firebase` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.x

```
const enhance = compose(
  connect(
    (state) => ({
      someKey: state.someData
    })
  ),
  firebaseConnect(
    (props, firebaseInstance) => [
      { path: `${props.someKey}/someData` }
    ]
  )
)
```

In 2.x

```
firebaseConnect(
  (props, store) => [
    { path: `${store.getState().someKey}/someData` }
  ]
)
```

Note how the 2nd argument in `firebaseConnect` changes from `firebaseInstance` to `store` from v1 to v2.

This should get you what you need.

Comment: I am using `firestoreConnect()` not `firebaseConnect()`

Answer (score 3):

Firestore (and all NoSQL databases) follow an alternating "*(parent)* collection / document / collection / document ..." hierarchical pattern. To synchronize a React component to subcollections and documents below the parent firestore collection, you need to pass the subcollection/subdocument hierarchy information as props to **firestoreConnect**.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { compose } from 'redux';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

    class PhotosScreen extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text> i plan the use this.props.images here </Text>
            {images && images.length ? <div> render your images here using this.props.images and images.map </div> : <p>No images</p>}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

   
        return {
            images  : state.firestore.data.images, // reference the subcollection of the user
            userId  : state.firestore.auth.uid     // assuming the 'doc id' is the same as the user's uid
        }                                          
    }

    export default compose(
        firestoreConnect((props) => 

            if (!props.userId) return []                 // sync only if the userId is available (in this case, if they are authenticated)
            return [
                {
                   collection     : 'users',             // parent collection
                   doc            : props.userId,        // sub-document
                   subcollections : [
                          {collection : 'images'}        // sub-collection
                   ],
                   storeAs        : 'images'
                }
             ]
        }),
        connect(mapStateToProps),
    )(PhotosScreen)
```